# I have python3 idle already installed on my computer, how can I install python2.7 idle too?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, python, python-2.7, idle-python

I need to run files programmed using 2.7 and if I go into terminal and give the command:

```
sudo apt-get install idle
```

It doesn't work.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
idle is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 196 not upgraded
```

That is what shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the version of IDLE that uses Python 2.7, install the `idle-python2.7` package. The command to run that version of IDLE, once it's installed, is also `idle-python2.7`. (Though you may also be able to select it from menu in your desktop environment.)

One way to install the `idle-python2.7` package is by running the commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install idle-python2.7
```

Then, to run it:

```
idle-python2.7
```

The approach shown above applies to installing any specific version of IDLE, though only a few tend to be provided in Ubuntu's repositories in any given release. You can see them all (and a few other packages) by listing packages whose names start with `idle`:

```
apt list 'idle*'
```

You may also find it helpful to search on https://packages.ubuntu.com for `idle`.

In most versions of Ubuntu so far, the `idle` package has provided IDLE for Python 2, while the `idle3` package provided it for Python 3, just as the `python` package provides Python 2--which it still does. But in the most recent versions, including 18.04, which appears to be what you are running, the `idle` package installs IDLE for Python 3.

Even though the `python` package and command is still Python 2, the `idle` package and command in the newest releases is IDLE for Python 3.